# On the optimization of docker image time-wait

Tags: linux, docker, time-wait

I started a docker image service. I want to modify the kernel parameter of this image (sysctl. CONF) to optimize time-wait, but I encountered the following problems.The code and version:
[image]

[image]

```
(custom_env) root@64d755e74e61:/etc# /sbin/sysctl -p
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_timeout: No such file or directory
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range": Read-only filesystem
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog: No such file or directory
sysctl: setting key "net.core.somaxconn": Read-only file system
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem: No such file or directory
(custom_env) root@64d755e74e61:/etc# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-210-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-009) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) ) #242-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 09:57:56 UTC 2021
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  That should include the actual source code you're running and the actual error messages you're getting, as text and not images.

Comment: (Since the Linux kernel is shared across all containers, a container often can't change sysctl parameters that would affect other containers and non-container processes.)